# Payflow using Hosted Pages: Is TENDER required in the secure token request?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

From [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#integrating-the-secure-token-with-the-hosted-checkout-pages) in the Payflow Developer Guide:

> To create a secure token, pass all parameters that you need to process the transaction except for **payment details** parameters such as the **credit card number**, **expiration date**, and **check number**. For details on transaction parameters, see [Submitting Credit Card Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-credit-card-transactions). In addition, pass the following Payflow parameters to create the secure token.

`TENDER` is listed as a required parameter [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#core-credit-card-parameters), in the "Submitting Credit Card Transactions" section. When using Hosted Pages, do I really need to ask the customer how they want to pay prior to passing them to Payflow? If not, could someone point me to where this is described in the documentation? I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: ETA: Changed `TXTYPE` to `TENDER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRXTYPE is the type of transaction you are doing, not what the customer is using.

Are you doing an (A)uthorization? (S)ale? (C)redit? (V)oid? etc.

With the hosted page token request, you pass over everything for the transaction *except* the payment method (credit card number or PayPal account).

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant "tender", not "txtype". I've actually been assuming/thinking/wondering if both of those values would be required (you'd need to pass both if you pass one).

Given your rep I'm going to assume you know what you're talking about. :) Is there anything more explicit in the documentation that states this, or are you basing this off the fact that you've personally seen that this is how it works? "payment details parameters such as the credit card number, expiration date, and check number" isn't the same thing as "payment method".

Comment: ^ Could you respond the question in my comment above? Thanks!

Comment: For hosted checkout page, to get the secure token, you would not pass over TENDER at all since you don't know the tender they will be using. This is based from my experience working with Advanced as well as from the guide (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#integrating-the-secure-token-with-the-hosted-checkout-pages)

Comment: That was the basis of my question—do I need to ask them what tender they'll be using prior to passing them to Payflow. I still don't think the guide makes this very clear. Sure, `TENDER` isn't mentioned in the token generation example they give, but it doesn't indicate that what _is_ in the example is an exhaustive list, and it never explicitly states what parameters are required.

Comment: You do not need to indicate TENDER as the system will determine it when the customer pays on the hosted Checkout page. (and will return a TENDER value to you).